# What is the cost of Live streaming using Adobe Media Server in amazon cloudfront in Amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, adobe, http-live-streaming, adobe-media-server

I am unable to understand the costing mechanism for Amazon aws live streaming. Can someone help me in finding out the cost for the following scenario:

Cost of m1.large instance of adobe media server in cloudfront in amazon aws = $0.43/hour

Number of simultaneous connections m1.large instance of adobe media server in cloudfront in amazon aws can handle = 100

When I encode the video and stream it to the Adobe media server in cloudfront, I will be encoding it in 300 kilobits/sec

My website is hosted in an aws micro instance and the free period has expired.

So, If I have a live streaming event coming up and I intend to have the live streaming for 1 hour and suppose for that entire 1 hour 100 simultaneous connections will be constantly there, then how much will be my cost?

Note: Amazon cost calculator says that the actual cost will be based on the data transfer on the ec2. So which Ec2 is it? The one where my website is hosted or the adobe one I created using cloudfront? So when 100 people are watching the live streaming on my website, the data transfer is between them and the ec2 instance where my website is hosted or is it between them and the Adobe Media server instance I created using cloudfront? If it is between them and the Adobe Media server instance I created using cloudfront then I think they already charged me $0.43 for 100 simultaneous connections.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, the origin server used by CloudFront would be your EC2 machine.

```
Ec2 Server as the Origin Server ---(1)---> CloudFront ---(2)---> Users
```

CloudFront is a Content Delivery service that works as this:

- When a request for certain content is received by a user, CloudFront checks its closest location for the presence of the content. If found, it is returned to the user
- If not, CloudFront contacts the Origin Server to fetch the content. It brings the content serves it to the user and caches the content for subsequent requests.

In order to calculate your costs, this is how you can work:

- The amount of data (and number of requests) that is transferred from your Ec2 server and CloudFront cache locations. This will  come under the head "Data transfer from EC2". This should happen once per request from CloudFront location assuming that CF caches your data for good enough time (1 hour in your case).
- The amount of data that is served from CloudFront (to the users).